# A "Needs Community Edit" Option for Reviewing First Posts When Reviewer is Unable to Edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, first-post-review

When reviewing first posts, there are often new questions that are poorly formatted and can be fixed without much effort. However, for reviewers who haven't reached 2000 reputation, it's very difficult to improve such posts. Personally, I often experienced:

> Suggested edit queue is full

(*Updated Stats*: 24 out of 35 times when I click "Edit")

or

> You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved.

I think the maximum number of edits pending is 5, and those edits usually take some time to be reviewed. Considering that one can review 40 posts every day in "First Post", I think **a "Needs Community Edit" option would be very helpful in the "First Posts" review** (Just like in Triage) **when the edit queue is full or when the user has reached their maximum number of pending edits**.

In addition, to address the issue that new users should learn how to format properly and we shouldn't just *fix it for them*, I think we could send a message to their inbox for a link to how to properly format a post once an edit has been made, so hopefully their formatting next time would be much better.

Currently, it has been a hard choice for me when I cannot edit and the post which has formatting issues.

- Flagging isn't appropriate since the issue can be fixed by the community
- Downvoting doesn't seem appropriate since the question is usually clear, only the formatting has some issues. I also don't want to discourage new users to ask questions just because of formatting
- Adding a comment is not always that helpful since the user might not very familiar with how to format it properly
- Upvoting isn't appropriate either since it can take a long time for others to understand it without the formatting (such as posting code as text)

Which leaves me in a very awkward situation here. In that case, I often have to "Skip" this review although I know how this post can potentially be fixed. Any suggestions on what actions might be more appropriate?

Comment: Leave the comment. If the user is not familiar how to format they have to learn sooner or later. Or skip. There is nothing wrong with skipping.

Comment: Wow, I am surprised someone is so motivated to run into limits. I'd give such requests the highest priority. Though specifically to new post formatting I don't think there is a big problem, high rep users often just do a quick edits before commenting/answering. I even do it before vote-closing. So skipping is not a problem.

Comment: Skipping is definitely not a problem but it isn't optimal either. If a reviewer can't edit then they should at least be able to reach out to people who *can* edit.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar *not wrong* is not what we're looking for, and neither skipping nor leaving a comment is the *optimal* solution. Leaving a comment doesn't ensure that the post will be fixed *properly* - I think there needs to be a way to send this post to a community edit queue if the reviewer is unable to edit (there's already one for triage so I assume it's not very difficult to do)

Comment: I am not strictly arguing against this feature request. But there are few things to consider. Chances that question is really good and that all that is needed is some formatting or minor spelling corrections are extremely small. While there is option for community to edit and improve questions, I am more in favor of OP fixing formatting issues as leaving formatting to the community is far from optimal - this is something OP should learn how to do and leaving comment is the best and most helpful action.

Comment: When it comes to pure spelling and grammar issues, I have never seen that being too much of a problem when the rest of the question is good. Even without queues such questions will be polished sooner or later, and usually grammar is not considered when determining closing eligibility, and most people will not downvote just because of grammatic issues.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I get your point, and I agree that it's definitely important for the OP to learn how to format themselves. To address that point, I think a possible add-on could be - when the reviewer chooses the "Needs Community Edit" option, it'll automatically add a comment to the post/send to the OP's inbox that links to a page where the OP could find help on how to format posts properly. (Just like when you flag a question as duplicate, it'll add a comment: "Does this answer your question...") That'll be much easier for the reviewer and very helpful for the OP too.

Comment: *"Adding a comment is not always that helpful since the user might not very familiar with how to format it properly"* - then why not comment directing them to some help. Something like: *"Your post is not properly formatted. Please read about [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [edit] it accordingly"* (raw: `Your post is not properly formatted. Please read about [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [edit] it accordingly`)

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is a good suggestion, but I think it would be better to have a function to do this automatically. Otherwise, the reviewer would have to copy the link into the comments for every post they think cannot be formatted properly, or store it somewhere else in Notes that they copy from every time - which isn't *optimal* either. It's much easier to have an option from the control panel to do so automatically when they are unable to edit.

Comment: I think this might work: have an additional option "Needs to Fix Formatting" when the reviewer is unable to edit for them to alert the OP on how to format, and after a certain period of time if no action is taken, it'll be sent to the community edit queue

Comment: @Parzival The main problem I see with passing format issues to another queue is it's too easy to look at a garbage question that may not even be answerable and have someone click a button to pass it along in order to just polish a turd

Comment: @charlietfl You're right, but it will be handled the similar way as Triage. If the post isn't clear and cannot be answered, downvoting and flagging will be the appropriate actions. I'm referring to posts which reviewers cannot edit but can be fixed by the community. Those unsalvagable questions will not be sent to the queue by reviewers if handled correctly

Comment: @Parzival That was just an extra suggestion. I didn't say anything against yours. I actually support it. But sitting and waiting for a UI change might be a long wait. In the meantime, you better find workarounds for your problem. One of them is the [AutoReviewComments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) which lets you set pre-defined comments that are easily pasted